# Centering Radio Buttons in a GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, radio-button, grid-layout

I am trying to create an application using GridLayout and I don't know how to center some radio buttons. The window ends up looking like: [image]

Here is how I added the radio buttons:

```
JPanel qArea = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,5));
...
qArea.add(new JPanel());
    qArea.add(o1);
    qArea.add(o2);
    qArea.add(o3);
    qArea.add(o4);
    while(i<50)
    {
        if (i%5 == 0)
            qArea.add(qs[cq++]);
        else
            qArea.add(buttons[crb++]);
        i++;
    }
```

Is there any way I can center the radio buttons inside their columns?

Comment: As you can see, the texts on the upper side are centered inside their columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
radioButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```